# I want a designated server to serve internal website ONLY using a common router

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking

What I'm looking to do is offer WiFi hotspot (no password required to connect) to local community around my house.

- My idea is to utilize a common router to propagate the signal but somehow port forward all connections to my internal server's website ONLY.
- The router will not be connected to the Internet.

Basically my motive is to propagate political content to my neighbors that connect to my router (information that would otherwise be censored to death through our weakest link...the IP Providers themselves!).

Again, the wireless I send out will not be connected to the internet but I cannot expect passersby to connect and KNOW to type in some local area network address (of the server).

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You need to search and read about "captive portal".

Answer (score 0):

As @DavidPostill pointed out in a comment the function you're looking for is called a Captive Portal.

Generally this will be run from the access point itself, or the access point would give the address to load by default. You might achieve this via your existing routers firmware (if it supports it) or may need to install a 3rd party firmware such as dd-wrt if it supports your device.

Otherwise you can buy dedicated devices to provide this, along with routing the wifi correctly for you.